# How to make GitHub to render XML files as a text ones during pull request?

Tags: xml, git, github, pull-request, gitattributes

When I'm submitting pull request, or solving conflicts, I want .xml files to be treated as text ones as well, since they are. Still, when I do said pull requests/solve conflicts, in GitHub interface I get only message as below:

[image: Error message]

I tried to adjust my [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file, but according to other Stack Overflow questions, it seems to be applicable only for local git, and doesn't affect GitHub side.

Also, when I try to view .xml files directly from the GitHub's file tree, I can watch them with no problem. And actual binary files like .db / .png / etc are shown there as binary properly. So this is the issue of only pull request merge / conflict solving interface.

Is there other way to make GitHub interpret .xml files as a text ones in said modes? In my project we have quite a lots of settings stored there, so we'd prefer to be able check changes online.